# Referring to properties of containing class when using internal structs in swift

Tags: swift, mvvm, protocols

I'm refactoring a project to use MVVM and using protocols to ensure that my view models have a consistent structure. This works fine for defining public properties relating to input and output (which are based on internal structs) but defining actions in the same way is proving problemmatic as, currently, they are defined as closures which have to refer to view model properties. If I use the same approach as I have to input and output properties, I don't think I can access properties of the containing instance.

Example:

```
protocol ViewModelType {
    associatedtype Input
    associatedtype Output
    associatedtype Action
}

final class MyViewModel: ViewModelType {
    struct Input { var test: String }
    struct Output { var result: String }
    struct Action { 
        lazy var createMyAction: Action<String, Void> = { ... closure to generate Action which uses a MyViewModel property }
    }
    var input: Input 
    var output: Output
    var action: Action
}
```

It's not a deal breaker if I can't do it, but I was curious as I can't see any way of getting access to the parent's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer to your question

Let's begin with a note that `createMyAction: Action<String, Void>` refers to the type (`struct`) named `Action` as if it was a generic, but you have not declared it as such and will thus not work.

And to answer your question of the nested `struct Action` can refer its outer `class MyViewModel` - yes you can refer `static` properties, like this:

```swift
struct Foo {
    struct Bar {
        let biz = Foo.buz
    }
    static let buz = "buz"
}

let foobar = Foo.Bar()
print(foobar.biz)
```

But you should probably avoid such circular references. And I will omit any ugly hack that might be able to achive such a circular reference on non static properties (would probably involve mutable optional types). It is a code smell.

## Suggestion for MVVM

Sounds like you would like to declare `Action` as a function? I'm using this protocol myself:

```swift
protocol ViewModelType {
    associatedtype Input
    associatedtype Output
    func transform(input: Input) -> Output
}
```

Originally inspired by [*SergDort's CleanArchitecture*](https://github.com/sergdort/CleanArchitectureRxSwift).

You can prepare an instance of `input` (containing `Observable`s) from the `UIViewController` and call the `transform` function and then map the `Output` of transform (being `Observables`s) to update the GUI.

**So this code assumes you have basic Reactive knowledge**. As for `Observable`s you can chose between [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) or [ReactiveSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift) - yes their names are similar.

If you are comfortable with Rx, it is an excellent way of achieving a nice MVVM architecture with simple async updates of the GUI. In the example below, you will find the type `Driver` which is documented [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Traits.md#driver), but the short explanation is that is what you want to use for **input from** views and **input to** views, since it updates the views on the GUI thread and it is guaranteed to not error out.

*CleanArchitecture* contains e.g. [`PostsViewModel`](https://github.com/sergdort/CleanArchitectureRxSwift/blob/f609ce2635f31449b2d75ac093c4652f25b9dbf8/CleanArchitectureRxSwift/Scenes/AllPosts/PostsViewModel.swift) :

```swift
final class PostsViewModel: ViewModelType {

    struct Input {
        let trigger: Driver<Void>
        let createPostTrigger: Driver<Void>
        let selection: Driver<IndexPath>
    }
    struct Output {
        let fetching: Driver<Bool>
        let posts: Driver<[PostItemViewModel]>
        let createPost: Driver<Void>
        let selectedPost: Driver<Post>
        let error: Driver<Error>
    }

    private let useCase: PostsUseCase
    private let navigator: PostsNavigator
    
    init(useCase: PostsUseCase, navigator: PostsNavigator) {
        self.useCase = useCase
        self.navigator = navigator
    }
    
    func transform(input: Input) -> Output {
        let activityIndicator = ActivityIndicator()
        let errorTracker = ErrorTracker()
        let posts = input.trigger.flatMapLatest {
            return self.useCase.posts()
                .trackActivity(activityIndicator)
                .trackError(errorTracker)
                .asDriverOnErrorJustComplete()
                .map { $0.map { PostItemViewModel(with: $0) } }
        }
        
        let fetching = activityIndicator.asDriver()
        let errors = errorTracker.asDriver()
        let selectedPost = input.selection
            .withLatestFrom(posts) { (indexPath, posts) -> Post in
                return posts[indexPath.row].post
            }
            .do(onNext: navigator.toPost)
        let createPost = input.createPostTrigger
            .do(onNext: navigator.toCreatePost)
        
        return Output(fetching: fetching,
                      posts: posts,
                      createPost: createPost,
                      selectedPost: selectedPost,
                      error: errors)
    }
}
```

Comment: I had "hacked" it by creating a struct (called Actions) containing publicly accessible getters for private lazy vars that defined the RxSwift actions I was after. It works but I did feel uncomfortable doing it which was probably my subconscious warning me of a code smell. I think the problem was that I was trying to treat the actions as a separate entity in its own right, rather than as an output of the VM (which of course, they are). Thanks for the pointer - I'll refactor and see if it will eliminate another issue I've just run into...

Comment: let me know if you want any more input. You could take a look at this iOS wallet app for the cryptocurrency Zilliqa named Zhip, I've written which is open source. Zhip uses this `transform(input) -> Output` pattern in its ViewModels. https://github.com/OpenZesame/Zhip